# Let $M$ be a real symmetric matrix. Are eigenvectors of the power $M^k$ also eigenvectors of $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Context:** (not really necessary for the question)

I'm looking at a discrete-time dynamical system on a graph. In some cases, the `state transition function' can be described using a modified form of the graph adjacency matrix, which we'll call $M$. Certain eigenvectors of $M$ correspond to periodic states of the dynamical system with period $1$ or $2$. Some eigenvectors of $M^k$ would, similarly, correspond to periods of length $k$. I'd like to show that it's impossible for $M^k$ to have some eigenvector that is *not* an eigenvector of $M$, to demonstrate that there are no periods of length greater than 2.

**Question:** Let $M$ be a symmetric matrix whose entries are all (non-negative) real values. Are all the eigenvectors of $M^k$ also eigenvectors of $M$? If so, how would I prove this / what is an accessible reference that has a proof?

My suspicion is that I should be able to use something like the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices, but I don't know how.

Comment: What about $M=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Consider $M := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Clearly, it is a symmetric matrix with non-negative, real entries.

It is also clear that $M^2$ is the $(2 \times 2)$-identity matrix, where every vector $\mathbb{R}^2 \ni v \neq 0$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue 1.

And yet, if we take for example $v= (1,0)^\top$, then $M \cdot v = (0,1)^\top$, so it's not an eigenvector for $M$.

Answer (score 2):

When $M$ has a real nonnegative spectrum, yes, because $M$ is a polynomial in $M^k$. More specifically, let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $M$. Let $p$ be any polynomial such that $p(\lambda_i^k)=\lambda_i$. (E.g. take $p$ as the Lagrange interpolation polynomial at the distinct eigenvalues of $M^k$.) Then $p(M^k)=M$. (If you don't see this, consider a diagonalisation of $M$.) It follows that if $M^kv_i=\lambda_iv_i$, then $Mv_i=p(M^k)v_i=p(\lambda_i^k)v_i=\lambda_iv_i$.

Comment: This is very useful, thanks!